# adding subview on self.tabbarcontroller.view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, iboutlet, addsubview

I have added a viewcontroller's view on self.tabbarcontroller.view. But in that case , I am unable to change frame of iboutlets in subview added. How to change the frames ?Please help.. thanks

```
- (void)addPopup
{
  popUpDataViewController = [[PopUpDataViewController alloc]init];
  popUpDataViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popUpData"];

  popUpDataViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
  CGRect oldFrame = popUpDataViewController.view.frame;
  oldFrame.size.height = oldFrame.size.height + self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
  popUpDataViewController.view.frame = oldFrame;

  [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:popUpDataViewController.view];

}
```

Comment: Don't add views. Set View controllers with – setViewControllers:animated: This is how UITabbarController works

Comment: there are view controllers for tabbar.. But on some button clicks on those viewcontrollers , I have to add few views as subview.. and those subviews should be added above the tabbar.. that is why using self.tabbarcontroller.view addsubview.. Please help